Pandas: Nested use of .loc returns different 'type' for the same field
Why do I get 2 different data types while indexing using .loc, even though i retrieve a single value/cell.
Background: I'm looking up values of df_source in df_map. I do not get string datatype for the matches when I do the below indexing.
# Just for reproducing. Note that we need to replace ```None``` with ```Nan```, as that is the case when we load the original dataframe from excel. But i cannot create a dict with ```Nan``` and so used ```None```

df_map = pd.DataFrame({'person': {0: 'jack',
  1: 'jack',
  2: 'jack',
  3: 'harry',
  4: 'harry',
  5: 'harry'},
 'country': {0: 'GE', 1: 'AUS', 2: 'AUS', 3: 'UK', 4: 'SP', 5: 'BR'},
 'product': {0: 'AA', 1: 'NT', 2: 'NT', 3: 'AA', 4: 'NT', 5: 'NT'},
 'account': {0: 'main1',
  1: 'main2',
  2: None,
  3: 'main2',
  4: 'main3',
  5: 'sub4'}})

df_source = pd.DataFrame({'country': {0: 'GE', 1: 'AUS'},
 'product': {0: 'AA', 1: 'NT'},
 'account': {0: 'main1', 1: 'sub2'}})

-------- case 1 -------------- 
i=1
# search in df_map
person = df_map.loc[(pd.isna(df_map['account']))\ 
                    & (df_map['country'] == df_source.loc[i,'country']) \
                    & (df_map['product'] == df_source.loc[i,'product']), 'person']
type(person)
>pandas.core.series.Series

-------- case 2 ---------------
person = df_map.loc[1, 'person']
type(person)
>str


Although both returns a single value, both are different types. How does .loc differ in this case, is it because of the nested use of it ?

Your first approach is called boolean indexing, this creates a boolean Series and uses this to select the matching row(s). This can yield zero, one, or more rows. In this particular case there is only one. This has nothing to do with the "nested use of loc".
In any case, the output is a Series, not a scalar.
If you know that there is only one match and want a scalar, you could squeeze:
i = 1
person = df_map.loc[(pd.isna(df_map['account']))
                    & (df_map['country'] == df_source.loc[i,'country'])
                    & (df_map['product'] == df_source.loc[i,'product']),
                    'person'].squeeze()

type(person)
# str

